# Getting a simple bibliography to work in ConTeXt

Tags: bibliographies, context, href

I'm trying to get a simple bibliography to work with ConTeXt. Here's what I have so far:

## `test.tex`

```
\usebtxdataset[bibliography.bib]

\starttext
 
  \startbodymatter
    See \cite[proofwiki]
  \stopbodymatter

  \startbackmatter
    \startsection[title=Bibliography]
      \placelistofpublications
    \stopsection
  \stopbackmatter
\stoptext
```

## `bibliography.bib`

```
@misc{
  proofwiki,
  title={{Definition:Collation - ProofWiki}},
  author={{ProofWiki}},
  journal={{ProofWiki}},
  year={2021}
}
```

## Question

When I compile test.tex it generates a pdf, the citation is included but the bibliography entry is not correctly typeset.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use `\placelistofpublications` somewhere

Comment: That was a typo, my question was edited. But nevermind, I think I found what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not including the following in my preamble:

`\usebtxdefinitions[aps]`

The next question I guess is whether ConTeXt support other specs like MLA or Chicago style. I tried MLA but it didn't seem to work. MkIV [bibliography manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf) states the following:

> At this time, we only provide two description files, with aps being an example of a number-based rather than an authoryear-based scheme; more style schemes may be added in the future and the customization of a rendering style will be described in a later chapter.